# VBA for word: why cannot access other opened documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

the following code always give me 1 no matter how many word documents I opened.

```
    Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox Application.Documents.Count
    End Sub
```

Could some one educate me why?  and then how to access all other word documents?

thanks.

Comment: Try opening a document using Word's Open dialog.

Comment: thank you Slaks!  the problem is that I'm programmatically creating another document from within the first one I opened.  I'm actually using Application.Documents.Open to create a new doc in the same application......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably opened each document in a separate application instance (in a separate session of WinWord.exe)

Do you see the documents in Word's Windows menu?  (Or, in 2007+, the Switch Documents menu)

Comment: what I did was: 1) click one file in a folder - open the first document. 2) using VBA to open another one from the same folder. I'm trying to shift from number 1 to number 2 doc.  then I eneded up not being able to find number 2 from number 1.  What I need to do in this case?  thanks!